# Is it possible to convert a string to a list index in Python (2.7)?

Tags: python-2.7

I am an absolute beginner currently working on a Tic Tac Toe game and in the below example I am stuck on how to convert a string (e.g. "row1[0]") to a list index (e.g. row1[0]). Basically, I am unsure why eval(aa) = a does not work, but, for example, row1[0] = a does work (and yes, I am aware that eval() is usually frowned upon but have been unable to find any alternatives, as dictionaries, exec, and compile have all failed).

Please also note this is not the full code, just one of my attempts at figuring out the above. Would really appreciate your input on this specific step, I've been unable to find an answer so far. Thanks.

```
row1 = [_,_,_]
row2 = [_,_,_]
row3 = [_,_,_]
a = raw_input("Player 1, choose your marker - X or O: ")
aa = raw_input("Player 1, choose box (row#[box # - 1]): ")
#Attempt at assigning "X" or "O" to a row index.
eval(aa) = a
print row1
print row2
print row3
```

Answer (score 0):

`eval('row1[0]') = 'X'` doesn't work for the same reason that `'a' = 'b'` would not work.

`eval('row1[0]')` returns the **value** of the list `row1` at index 0, not the reference to it.

If `row1` is `['', '', '']` then `eval(row1[0])` will return an empty string (`''`), and you can't assign the string `'X'` to an empty string.

If you would like to use `eval` then the user will have to input the list name and the index separately.

```
row1 = ['', '', '']
eval('row1')[0] = 'X'
print row1
# ['X', '', '']
```

I realize that you are a beginner but my suggestion is to use a class so you will be able to use `getattr`. `getattr` is a built-in function in Python that accepts an object and a string and returns the object's attribute with that name.

```
class Board(object):
     def __init__(self):
          self.row1 = ['', '', '']
          self.row2 = ['', '', '']
          self.row3 = ['' ,'', '']

board = Board()
shape = raw_input("Player 1, choose your marker - X or O: ")
row_and_col = raw_input("Player 1, choose box (row#,col#): ")   # user will input 1,0
                                                                # for example

row_number, col_number = row_and_col.split(',')  # split divides the string it is called
                                                 # upon with the character it gets as
                                                 # the argument. In this case
                                                 # 'row_and_col' is '1,0' so after this
                                                 # line row_number is '1' and col_number
                                                 # is '0'

relevant_row = getattr(board, 'row' + row_number)
# now relevant_row actually holds the reference to the list,
# not its value as eval would have returned

relevant_row[int(col_number)] = shape
```

Comment: Thank you DeepSpace, I hadn't made it to object oriented programming yet; this definitely makes a lot more sense than eval().